# Get count of records changing status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure the best way to get a count of how many times a record was sent back to the user (Status changed from 3 or 4 back to 1)

this is what my data looks like

```
ID   record_id  status_id
1    10909      2           
2    10909      3
3    10909      1
4    10909      3
5    10909      3
6    10909      4
7    10909      5
```

Comment: How do you determine if a row went "back" to 1; I see no way to retain the order of your data by use of an `ORDER BY`, and it can't be based on ordinal position of the row as no such thing exists (rows are stored in **unordered** heaps in a table).

Comment: If you simply want to count the number of rows that have the `status_ID` of `1`, what's wrong with `COUNT`? What have you tried to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Yep. We need a timestamp or rownumber/version here. Otherwise this data is completely meaningless. We couldn't even tell you which status is current. Say it with me again: **The order in which a row is inserted into a table is not always the same way the row is stored**. And therefore the inverse is also true: the order in which a row is physically stored in a table does not imply anything about the order in which the row was inserted.

Comment: And the order in which the data was inserted or is stored also implies nothing about the order it may be returned to you in a SELECT query. So...in your data above, can you please tell us how you are going to work out what the correct order is? Do you have a third column which tells you this? If so we need to see it. If not you need to add it before you can start thinking about solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" or "next" row, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Your data does not seem to have such a column.  But if you did, you could use `lag()`:

```
select record_id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by record_id order by <ordering column>) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where status = 1 and prev_status in (3, 4)
group by record_id;
```

Comment: for anyone else who wants to better understand your answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017